# Why was my question removed? 

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

Here's the [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4dXbANAXBHEJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/9836001/how-do-i-prevent-a-gtkaspectframe-from-wasting-space+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk) of the question, [+10k link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836001/how-do-i-prevent-a-gtkaspectframe-from-wasting-space).

I thought it was a good question, and I put serious effort into conveying what I wished to know as clearly as possible. Furthermore, I couldn't find a similar question on Stack Overflow, and it's fully within the scope of this site as far as I can tell.

So someone deleted it without even giving a reason? Without any notification?

Comment: Was the question closed?

Comment: @YannisRizos - It was deleted. No note of who deleted it though.

Comment: Huh? This is strange.

Comment: @Oded Ah, when there's no note, it's usually that evil mod, [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)...

Comment: It seems like a reasonable question to me, it's a shame it didn't attract at least one answer. I've cast an undelete vote, if others see fit they'll do the same, we can then negate that one down vote and hopefully someone will have an answer for it in the future.

Comment: @slugster you convinced me, we need 1 more. :)

Comment: Thank you for the undelete votes! My question has now risen from the grave.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was deleted by the system after being identified as "abandoned", see the official post about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/152859):

> Just to formally document the exact policies we have in place to remove old abandoned / dead questions:
>
> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has -1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

Your question was posted over two months ago, has -1 score and no answers and it's not locked - thus got deleted by the system scheduled task.

Edit: this same process also delete zero scored questions:

> **If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 or a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> This check is run every week across all sites.

Comment: Ahh, good find. It *would* be fair to tell question owners about this, though.

Comment: @Pekka I think authors currently don't get any notification, even when their post is deleted by a moderator or by community members but yes, I agree such notification should be in place.

Comment: What I find very lame is that the question remained at a score of zero for many months since I posted it. Then suddenly, to my surprise, somebody voted it down a few days ago, and almost immediately afterward it gets completely deleted. I think questions shouldn't be deleted until at least 30 days (preferably longer) _after the downvote to a negative score_, no?

Comment: @WillBuddha That would make sense, but I think right now the counter starts when you posted the question. Since you were most affected by this, I think you should post a feature request for a notification on auto deletes and for a more sensible counter.

Comment: @WillBuddha the task runs weekly, apparently every Saturday. Anyway your question is now undeleted so you have at least 6 days to earn either answers or upvotes to keep it alive for good. :)