# Allow any user access to their posts deleted not by themselves at any time, in a convenient way

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I propose any user can access their posts deleted not by themselves at any time, in a convenient way. I know that the option of viewing recently deleted posts under one's own "Questions" tab, but the questions there last only a few days.

The reason of my proposal is: that can keep record of what questions they have had, which is  useful when they encounter the same problem again in the future,:

- That can remind them the questions haven't been solved yet, not some questions solved before but now they forget how to do it again (which can be very misleading),
- That can help to find out how related, similar and different the previous questions and the current ones are, which can help to identify the causes of the problems and illuminate the solutions.
- When others had made comments and answers to the deleted posts, keeping the posts viewable to the post owner is even more useful.

Comment: Related: [Ensure that users can access feedback on deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135362/262755)