# Was a question of mine deleted / removed? How do I tell?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I ***THINK*** I asked a question on Stack Overflow years ago, but I can't find it. Was it deleted / removed? How do I tell?

From my memory (which could be false), the question was about "entropy" and asked on either Stack Overflow or Cross Validated. The question probably had an "R" tag. Reading through the auto-deleted criteria [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion) or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135354/why-was-my-question-removed?newreg=eb5c6a980733457b9dbedd25982e46f2), I doubt it met the criteria. Again from memory, the question received at least 1 answer and a handful of comments.

How does one tell if a question was deleted / removed (e.g., are there notifications or timeline indicators)? If a question was indeed deleted, how does one find it?

**Note**: while I am curious as to the *why* my question might have been deleted (the context), my core questions is *how to tell* if question is deleted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is embarrassing but I found your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698464/weighting-brand-entropy-using-frequency-of-purchases-weighting-a-zero).

I used a SEDE query to narrow down the number of posts I had to visit: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1411279

Your question was deleted by a moderator two years ago after it was closed for being too broad by five close voters. A comment under your question reads:

> It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

I have now read your question three times and I honestly can't find the "separate" questions the comment talks about. Worst of all: that means the close reason is bogus and that a moderator followed up with a binding delete vote is unexplainable. Unless a [burnination took all closed questions with it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311999/578411) ...

I've gone ahead and pinged the moderator involved and they confirmed the burnination was the trigger to delete your question.

If you only wanted to have access to that question again, you now can. If you feel undeletion is warranted then do flag for a moderator as you can't undelete it on your own. In anticipation on that I've already removed the "weight" tag from the question to prevent it from becoming unburninated at undeletion.

Guess what? Undeleted!

Comment: What's the embarrassing part?

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm not supposed to find other users deleted questions. I'm not a diamond.

Comment: @rene maybe then file a bug report about an abuse of the system (or it might be better as a feature request to make this harder for users to do?)

Comment: @EkadhSingh I'm not required to turn myself in but feel free to bring my abuse up to the proper authorities so they can resolve this.

Comment: The penalty for this abuse is to stand in elections and get a diamond.

Comment: @rene I think the reason moderators saw two questions is they saw the word "entropy" and they saw the word "frequency" and interpreted it as "how to calculate entropy?" and "how to calculate the frequency." My core question, that Paul Brodersen answered, is "how to create a measure the incorporates both "entropy" and "frequency."

Comment: @rene also possible moderators saw two questions because they saw "weight by 0" and "entropy." As I think about it, this is more likely the reason. But the "weight by 0" question can be answered separately and mathematically, but is necessary context for my core question.